# airplayit replacement

Tags: ios, streaming

I was using Aitplayit on my iPhone and iPad and it worked perfectly.  After updating to iOS 7, it no longer works properly. After visiting their website over some time, it definitely appears its no longer supported.

I looked for replacements, and I tried a few, but none seemed to work as well as Airplayit did.

Any suggestions for a replacement?

PS I use a PC for the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use.  Streamtomeme

It is much better than airplayit and has windows server software.

http://zqueue.com/streamtome/

The app is $2.99.  But we'll worth it.   Server is free

Comment: At first glance it looks just like AirplayIt...  Sucks that it isnt free, but it looks like it will work.  Thanks.